# How XOR works in my code?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg, encryption, xor

I have this assembly code:

```
XOR DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX],1234567
```

And what it does is just xoring the first 4 bytes of EAX with 1234567.
So if the first 4 bytes are :

```
31 32 31 32
```

After xor they become:

```
56 77 12 33
```

I tried many xor Calculators to understand how it was xored with no luck
any help?

Answer (score 2):

What may be confusing you is the fact that memory on x86 processors uses [*little-endian layout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The four bytes `31 32 31 32`, when interpreted as a 4-byte integer (dword), become `0x32313231`. If we perform xor operation  on it:

```
0x32313231^0x1234567=0x33127756
```

And putting  0x33127756 back into little-endian memory order we get:

```
56 77 12 33
```

Comment: Now i understand it much better thank you!

Comment: Then you should accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The command you refer to is a good example for CISC architectures:

```
XOR DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX],1234567
```

This first add the values of `ECX` and `EAX`, then interprets the sum as a memory address and xors **the value at that location with** `1234567`

Also, please note that the `EAX` register is always 4-byte sized. For less bytes, you may use `ax`, `al` or `ah` and for higher (8-byte) values you may use `RAX` (on 64 bit systems). Please note these names are referring to sections of the same register.